# Multiple app icons for same app in app drawer

Tags: android

I have created an android app and I am currently working on the navigation between the different screens.

I have four activities or classes: `splashScreen`, `listScreen`, `setLocationScreen`, `MainActivity`.

the navigation runs just fine, however, when I run the app and open the device, in the app tray I find three different apps each one running one of the screens.

Anyway to have just one app icon that launches the `MainActivity`? so I can only run the app from the beginning of the program and not each one alone?

Comment: Please show us the Activity section of your manifest, as well as the method used to launch a new `Intent`.

Comment: could you please remove iOS tag from the question?

Comment: @Ujjwal I've already done that, edit is pending review

Comment: @camelCaseCoder : oh ok.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

In **AndroidManifest.xml**

Remove

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

from all activities **except** for the one(in your case `MainActivity`) you want to be launched when app is opened

Answer (score 0):

Call your intent like so:

```
Intent in =new Intent(splashScreen.this, StartActivity.class);
finish();
startActivity(in);
```